# How does Variational Autoencoder approximate the joint probability distribution?

Tags: neural-networks, joint-distribution, autoencoders, variational-bayes, variational-inference

I know that in Variational Inference the idea is to approximate the posterior **P(z|x, y)** and I know that **Variational AutoEncoders (VAEs)** use the idea of variational inference through neural network architecture to approximate **P(z|x)** in the encoding phase and **P(x|z)** through decoding.

However, I cannot understand how VAEs are able to model the joint probability distribution and where this joint probability distribution is calculated in the encoder-decoder architecture. I am also wondering if the low dimensional embeddings created through encoding phase are the same as the latent space **P(z)**?